# Why isn't my array incrementing properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am in a C++ class and I am having trouble with the project. The idea of the project is to create an ordering application using structs and arrays. As far as I can tell the program is working as intended except for the how many items of each item the person ordered part of my printMenu function. If I am mistaken and or you find more errors please let me know.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct dinnerItemType
{
    string dinnerItem;
    double dinnerPrice;
    int dinnerOrdered;
};

void getFood(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int &size);
void printMenu(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int size);
void printCheck(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int size);

//Defines the global tax constant of 6%
const double TAX = 0.06;

int main()
{
    dinnerItemType ourMenu[150];
    int size = 0;

    getFood(ourMenu, size);

    printMenu(ourMenu, size);

    printCheck(ourMenu, size);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getFood(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int &size)
{
    ourMenu[0].dinnerItem = "Chicken Sandwich";
    ourMenu[0].dinnerPrice = 4.45;
    ourMenu[0].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[1].dinnerItem = "Fries";
    ourMenu[1].dinnerPrice = 2.47;
    ourMenu[1].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[2].dinnerItem = "Truffle Fries";
    ourMenu[2].dinnerPrice = 0.97;
    ourMenu[2].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[3].dinnerItem = "Filet 8oz";
    ourMenu[3].dinnerPrice = 11.99;
    ourMenu[3].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[4].dinnerItem = "Fruit Basket";
    ourMenu[4].dinnerPrice = 2.44;
    ourMenu[4].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[5].dinnerItem = "Tea";
    ourMenu[5].dinnerPrice = 0.69;
    ourMenu[5].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    ourMenu[6].dinnerItem = "Water";
    ourMenu[6].dinnerPrice = 0.25;
    ourMenu[6].dinnerOrdered = 0;

    size = 7;
}

void printMenu(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int size)
{

    int number;
    int amount;

    cout << "Welcome to the restraunt here are your menu items: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ")";
        cout << ourMenu[i].dinnerItem
             << "$"
             << ourMenu[i].dinnerPrice
             << endl;
    }

    cout << "To order just type in the number associated with the menu item and hit enter.\n"
         << "Once you have completed your order just type in 0 to go to checkout.\n";
    cin >> number;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 8)
        {
            ourMenu[number - 1].dinnerOrdered++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The number does not coorispond with a menu item please try again.\n";
        }

        cout << "To order just type in the number associated with the menu item and hit enter.\n"
             << "Once you have completed your order just type in 0 to go to checkout.\n";
        cin >> number;
    }
}

void printCheck(dinnerItemType ourMenu[], int size)
{
    double total = 0;

    cout << "Your Bill: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (ourMenu[i].dinnerOrdered > 0)
        {
            total += ourMenu[i].dinnerPrice;
        }
    }

    cout << "Tax: $ " << fixed << setprecision(2) << (total * TAX);
    cout << " Ammount Due: $" << (total + (total * TAX)) << endl;
    cout << "Thank you come again!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please better explain what your issue is. Considering condensing to just a [mcve] also. Are the wrong dinners being updated, or are no dinners being updated?

Comment: `amount` is unused in `printMenu`

Comment: Using a `double` variable to represent an amount of money is [considered dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency). Better to use integer-type variables representing a number of cents for all computations, and use decimal form just for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
total += ourMenu[i].dinnerPrice;
```

is only adding the cost of one meal to the total, regardless of how many times that meal is ordered.

To fix it: simply multiple the price by the number of times it is ordered:

```
total += ourMenu[i].dinnerPrice * ourMenu[i].dinnerOrdered;
```